# RegEx: Find lists of words containing specific string - Python

Tags: python, python-re, findall

I'm looking to find the words containing any of the following sequences: 'tion', 'ex' 'ph' 'ost', 'ist', 'ast'.

Here is my function so far:

```
def latin_ish_words(text):
        return re.findall('tion|ex|ph|ost|ist|ast+\b', text, re.I))
```

However, this is only returning the specific sequence rather than the full words.

Example 1: `latin_ish_words("This functions as expected")`
returns `['tion', 'ex']`, whereas I am looking for `["functions", "expected"]`.

Example 2: text = `'Philosophy ex nihilo existed in the past'` returns `['Ph', 'ph', 'ex', 'ex']`, whereas I am looking for `['Philosophy', 'ex', 'existed', 'past']`

Looking at the official Re documentation, I thought `'\b'` returned the full word?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to confirm, why should example 2 match "past" ? Is the regex supposed to read ```ast+``` rather than ```ost+``` ?

Comment: Great spot - thanks for this. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can try capture the prefix and post fix of the word using `[a-z]*`.

```
def latin_ish_words(text):
    return re.findall(r'\b([a-z]*(tion|ex|ph|ost)[a-z]*)\b', text, re.I)

In [1]: latin_ish_words("Philosophy ex nihilo existed in the past")
Out[1]: [('Philosophy', 'ph'), ('ex', 'ex'), ('existed', 'ex')]
```

The words you are trying to capture are first element of each tuple in the result list.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe splitting the sentence and checking each word individually?

```
import re

def latin_ish_words(text):
    words = text.split(' ')
    matched_words = []

    for word in words:
        if re.findall('tion|ex|ph|ost', word, re.I):
            matched_words.append(word)

    return matched_words
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
def latin_ish_words(text):
        return re.findall(r'(\w*(?:tion|ex|ph|ost|ast)\w*)', text, re.I)

text = 'Philosophy ex nihilo existed in the past.'
latin_ish_words(text)
```

It gives:

```
['Philosophy', 'ex', 'existed', 'past']
```

`(?: )` indicates a non-capturing group i.e. a pattern that should be matched but should not be returned by itself as one of `re.findall()` results.